# What is the difference between `$/sbin/restart nginx` and `$service nginx restart`?

Tags: linux, nginx, amazon-linux

I want to restart `nginx` after increasing the file descriptor limit in `/etc/security/limits.d/nginx.conf` and I need to restart the nginx processes for the change to take effect.

Should I use `$/sbin/restart nginx` or `$service nginx restart` and what is the difference?

---

For reference what `/sbin/restart` is:

```
$ /sbin/restart --help
Usage: restart [OPTION]... JOB [KEY=VALUE]...
Restart job.

Options:
  -n, --no-wait               do not wait for job to restart before exiting
      --system                use D-Bus system bus to connect to init daemon
      --dest=NAME             destination well-known name on system bus
  -q, --quiet                 reduce output to errors only
  -v, --verbose               increase output to include informational messages
      --help                  display this help and exit
      --version               output version information and exit

JOB is the name of the job that is to be restarted, this may be followed by zero or more environment variables to be defined in the job after
restarting.

The environment also serves to distinguish between job instances, and thus decide which of multiple instances will be restarted.

Report bugs at <https://launchpad.net/upstart/+bugs>
```

Answer (score 1):

with `sbin/nginx` You send command directly to nginx.

service does the same (check screenshot):

[image: screenshot]

P.S. in my ubuntu server I don't have  `/sbin/restart`, if You have it try to do `cat /sbin/restart`

Comment: Thanks, I added the `/sbin/restart` help to the question. I'm confused because it talks about `jobs`, is that the same as a process, and is that the same as a service?

Comment: I'm seeing `/sbin/restart` for the first time and googling does not give me anything. so if You want restart nginx use: `service nginx restart` or `systemctl restart nginx`   - `/sbin` folder seems creepy (since `init` script is there) so I don't think that You should user `/sbin/restart`

Comment: Maybe it's specific to Amazon Linux. For example, AWS recommends `/sbin/restart nodejs` to restart node. https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/instance-configuration/nodejs-increase-file-descriptors.config

Comment: Well, they don't mention to use it for nginx though. So I want to understand the difference. All commands restart nginx, but I'm not sure if every command does it equally gracefully.

Comment: @Manuel btw check this: https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/instance-configuration/change-nginx-max-body-size.config#L26